# Query all customers/users and check for duplicate information

Tags: plugins, php

I am looking to writing a quick plugin that will basically check the information in a customer's order and/or account, against other accounts in the database.

The reason being is, we have some customers we need to ban from time to time (rare, but necessary). I would like to ensure that if an order comes in, I can run a check against the database to see if the order's billing information matches any accounts in the database (other than the one currently ordering).

For example:

```
if( $order_phone_number == $any_number_in_database ){
    echo 'Potential match on different account.';
}
```

A script I currently have should allow me to query the database decently. Getting order details and comparing them isn't a problem. I am just wondering if there is a quicker, more efficient way to compare the order once it is sent, and alert the back-end.

My current plan is to run the check before the admin order email fires off, and include the check in that email (as well as on the order information page). Is this a bad idea? Is there a better way to go about this?

```
function GetSubscriberUserData()
{
$DBRecord = array();
$args = array(
    'role'    => 'Subscriber',
    'orderby' => 'last_name',
    'order'   => 'ASC'
);
$users = get_users( $args );
$i=0;
foreach ( $users as $user )
  {
  $DBRecord[$i]['role']           = "Subscriber";   
  $DBRecord[$i]['WPId']           = $user->ID;  
  $DBRecord[$i]['FirstName']      = $user->first_name;
  $DBRecord[$i]['LastName']       = $user->last_name;
  $DBRecord[$i]['RegisteredDate'] = $user->user_registered;
  $DBRecord[$i]['Email']          = $user->user_email;

  $UserData                      = get_user_meta( $user->ID );  
  $DBRecord[$i]['Company']        = $UserData['billing_company'][0];    
  $DBRecord[$i]['Address']        = $UserData['billing_address_1'][0];
  $DBRecord[$i]['City']           = $UserData['billing_city'][0];
  $DBRecord[$i]['State']          = $UserData['billing_state'][0];
  $DBRecord[$i]['PostCode']       = $UserData['billing_postcode'][0];
  $DBRecord[$i]['Country']        = $UserData['billing_country'][0];
  $DBRecord[$i]['Phone']          = $UserData['billing_phone'][0];
  i++;
  }
return DBRecord;
}
```